# Create Publishing HTML Site Column using PnPPowershell SP2016

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I'm trying to create a sharepoint 2016 site column using PnP powershell.

when I create a single line of text using the command below it works:

```
 Add-PnPField -DisplayName "column1" -InternalName "column1" -Group "PnPGroup" -Type Text
```

But I can't create a "Publishing HTML" column using this command :

```
 Add-PnPField -DisplayName "htmlcolumn" -InternalName "htmlcolumn" -Group "PnPGroup" -Type HTML
```

Can you tell me which is the appropriate type to create a "Publishing HTML" column ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Add-PnPFieldFromXml` to add the field as below:

```
$guid = New-Guid
$xml = '<Field Type="HTML" Name="htmlcolumn" DisplayName="htmlcolumn" Group="PnPGroup" StaticName="htmlcolumn" RichText="TRUE" ID="{'+$guid.Guid+'}" RichTextMode="FullHtml" />'

Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $xml
```

After that, you can see in the site columns as:

[image]

Reference - [Add-PnPFieldFromXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfieldfromxml?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: thanks for the answer is there any possibility to create it using Add-PnPField command ?

Comment: no, it is not supported at the moment. We need to use `Add-PnPFieldFromXml` for such special field types

Comment: cheers, happy to help. You can accept it as [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkmark besides the answer. Also, you can consider upvoting it as well if it helped you :)